# How to upload images cross domain (support all browser and mobile browsers)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, upload, cors

I have created API which helps developers upload images to their virtual folder.I have done everything but I have seen that cross domain upload doesn't seems to work when trying with mobile,how can I solve this?Deskop version works perfectly but mobile doesn't seems to work.And I have tested it same domain it worked but if it is cross domain it begin to not work,and fail.

**Note:** I have tested CORS but works only on desktop not on mobile,I know that I am not able to use jsonp in this case because I am uploading image and it cannot be done by jsonp.If Cors is not sollution How can I create cross browser,mobile supported upload process?

**Example:**http://newtimebox.com/demos/OOS_engine_API/upload.php , it works with desktop , but fail on mobile

Console says problem is `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.newtimebox.com/Controller/upload.php?connect_key=‌​tmp873ap_k958a7…7b9f‌​a25591dc4a472e74aeb1‌​cd89fe590b558a73a72a‌​982b58a73a72a986158a‌​73a72a9896. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://www.newtimebox.com', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.newtimebox.com' is therefore not allowed access. but I have just wrote one line which header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

Comment: why some people gave my question -2? is not it normal question?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with any and all errors that are thrown

Comment: @charlietfl I am not able to get any error message because error happen only on mobile,even I have used https://jsconsole.com .But I gave example page ,so if you tested it on mobile, you will probably see that it is not working , but it will work on desktop

Comment: lots of mobile emulator tools around

Comment: @charlietfl yes and I have used one of them which is called like jsconsole.com  and it doesnt shows any error

Comment: If you have an Android phone, connect it to your PC and open chrome://inspect/ to see console for the webpage in your mobile chrome and get errors.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer I didn't know this, thanks :), it says problem is `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.newtimebox.com/Controller/upload.php?connect_key=tmp873ap_k958a7…7b9fa25591dc4a472e74aeb1cd89fe590b558a73a72a982b58a73a72a986158a73a72a9896. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://www.newtimebox.com', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.newtimebox.com' is therefore not allowed access`. but I have just wrote one line which `header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find cross browser solution but I have found my problem sollution,I got above error because I called that method from my subdomain(it is wierd).if I call that from http://example.com it works but if I call this from http://www.example.com it is not working